# Symfony framework on Cloud9

Tags: symfony, cloud9-ide

Is there a way to setup a Symfony project on Cloud9?

I found some articles on creating Yii projects this way, but nothing on Symfony.

Comment: https://github.com/qyi/C9Symfony ?

Comment: Can you please write short instructions on how to use it?

Comment: I've no idea, I just make a quick search on Google ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have the answer.

https://docs.c9.io/docs/symfony2

I already create one.

Answer (score 1):

Note : I assume you are currently on an empty project/repository.

Run the following commands :

1. Download the composer.phar executable : `$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
2. Create the project on the current folder : `$ php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition projectName/`

External links :

- [The Symfony Book](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html)
- [Composer project on github](https://github.com/composer/composer)