# How to set up Symfony2 on Cloud9?

Tags: symfony, configuration, ide, server, cloud9-ide

I've setup Symfony2 on Cloud9 following this [Symfony on Cloud9 Guide](https://docs.c9.io/docs/symfony2).  When I preview the running application at (https://appname-username.c9users.io) it just serves up my file list:

```
Index of /
Name    Last modified    Size    Description
LICENSE
etc...
```

- Have I failed to setup a **configuration** somewhere?
- Should I be pointing my browser to a different **url**?

Thank you for help!

---

- I've followed this [Symfony on Cloud9 Guide](https://docs.c9.io/docs/symfony2) multiple times.
- I have this issue regardless of whether I install the acmedemo.
- I haven't been able to find the answer in [The Symfony Book](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html).
- This Stackoverflow did not help: [Symfony framework on Cloud9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808424/symfony-framework-on-cloud9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **New Run Configuration** window clearly says:

`Starting Apache httpd, serving https://appname-username.c9users.io/web/app_dev.php.`

Point browser at:
`https://appname-username.c9users.io/web/app_dev.php`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can install Symfony 3.2 successfully:

Follow the official installation documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

Create a new Symfony project:

```
symfony new my_project_name
```

Move content of project directory one level higher and delete that empty directory:

```
mv my_project_name/* .
rm -rf my_project_name
```

As Symfony is serving its content from the web directory, we need to modify the apache config using nano (a text editor):

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-cloud9.conf
```

Change the DocumentRoot to the following:

```
// Change this line
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/workspace
// To this
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/workspace/web
```

To save the file, Write Out, Enter, then Close (or press F2, Y, then Enter).

Open web/app.php and toggle your project to production mode:

```
// Change this line
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
// To this
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Save.

Start your Cloud9 server as usual with the green "Run Project" button.

Happy coding!